# can we use too many malloc and free in c program

Tags: malloc

is it ok to call too many malloc & free in a program?

i have a program that does malloc and free for each record. Although it sounds bad, does it have performance issue if i use too many malloc and free ?

Comment: Post the code maybe. It's easy to check if it'll be faster with fewer or no mallocs.

Answer (score 6):

Most modern `malloc(3)` implementations work like a memory pool. Since most modern OSes treat memory with pages (usually 4KB size), a malloc will probably request at least 4KB from the OS.

Suppose you keep calling `malloc` with 32. In your first malloc, at least one new page is requested from the OS (via `sbrk(2)` on unix). The successive mallocs have nothing to do with the OS, they just return you the next free chunk of memory in the memory pool as long as memory is available. So, calling `malloc` many times is not a big deal, usually. The point here is that system calls (the communication between the user process and OS) are usually expensive and `malloc` tries its best to avoid as much as possible.

`free` is similar too. When you free memory, usually OS isn't notified about that. When a page is totally freed, the page *may be* returned to the OS. Some implementations do not return the page to the OS unless the process already holds many unused pages.

To sum it up, `malloc` and `free` are like generic memory managers working with arbitrary size. The problem you might face is that `malloc` *is designed to* work with arbitrary size allocations, which might be slower than a memory manager that's designed to work with fixed size allocations. If you're usually allocating the same types of memory, you might be better off with implementing your own memory pool. Another case would be that `malloc` calls involve locking/unlocking in most modern implementations to support multithreading. If you're working with a single thread, that might also be an overhead: another reason to implement your own memory pool.

You might also want to work with different malloc implementations, benchmark them and decide to go with either one. Starting with a clean implementation and stripping off unnecessary parts might also be a good idea here.

Answer (score 1):

By definition 'too many' is 'too many'.

But more seriously, on most systems heap allocation is reasonably fast - because its done *a lot*. Allocating space for a record each time its processed doesn't sound bad.

The real answer is : write your program and measure its speed, is it acceptable? If not then profile it and find where the bottlenecks are - my 10c says it wont be heap processing

Answer (score 1):

yes/no.  Large volumes of malloc/free can cause the heap to be fragmented to the point where malloc can fail.   It is less of an issue now that memory is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 1):

There is *some* overhead in calling malloc, but not a lot. `malloc` basically has to go to through the heap and find a block of memory that is unused and large enough to hold the number of bytes you asked for, then it designates that block as used and tells the operating system to `mmap` it for you and returns a pointer to that block.

It's a few steps, but really not a lot of work for your computer. The difference between using malloc to get memory for you, and putting a variable on the stack is a handful of instructions, and a system call, and unless you're programming on an embedded system, you honestly shouldn't worry about it. You'll only take a real performance hit if you allocate so much memory that you actually run out of RAM (in which case your Virtual Memory Manager will have to move some things into the swap space to make more room - as it turns out, [malloc never fails](https://scvalex.net/posts/6/))!

Freeing memory is even easier than allocating it, and in the end it's better to free what you allocate (future `malloc` calls will be faster, more memory will be available).

In short, use malloc to your hearts content! Decades of advances in technology have worked hard to earn you that right, there's no sense squandering it!